# Firebase Dynamic Links looses UTM parameters

Tags: firebase-dynamic-links

we have successfully implemented dynamic links natively on iOS, but we loose our UTM parameters, when the User installs his App via AppStore.

Details:
In case a user has not installed the targeted App, then the user will be redirected to the AppStore after tabbing on the dynamic link. After installing the app and open it, the UTM parameters are not being sent to Google Analytics.
I assume these UTM parameters get lost during the AppStore redirect, as this Issue does not reproduce for users, who have already installed the App. Also for Android, we could not reproduce this.

Any hints on that? Thanks!